# Global conformal Killing vector fields in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $t$ is a globally smooth Killing coordinate function in $(M,g)$ such that $\partial_t$ is a Killing vector field. This gives rise to an embedding $\mathbb R \times \Omega$ for the manifold $M$. Under what conditions can we deduce that the metric must take the form:
$$ g(t,x) = \,dt^2+ 2\,dt\otimes \eta + h $$
where $\eta$ is a one-form and $h$ is a Riemannian metric on $\Omega$ with both $\eta$ and $h$ independent of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the general form of metric tensor that is invariant with respect to vertical shifts:
$$ g(t,x) = f(x){\cdot} dt^2+ 2{\cdot} dt\circ \eta + h.$$

Evidently, $g(\partial_t,\partial_t)=f(x)$.
So it is sufficient to assume $g(\partial_t,\partial_t)=1$.